# percentage of observations that meet two conditions in two different columns (in r)

Tags: r

I have a great database which columns are species presence and mining projects presence (presence=1, ausence=0) and rows are geopraphic locations (pixels). 
I want to get the percentage of pixels when specie1=1 & mining project=1 regarding specie1=1. I have more than 100 species, so I need a kind of loop in order to be more eficient

I have tried to do a loop with for, but I dont know what is "i".

Here an example that I want to do

```r
x <- data.frame("dog" = c(1,1,0,0,1,1), "cat" = c(1,0,0,0,1,1), 
+                 "trap" = c(1,1,0,1,0,1))
> x
  dog cat trap
1   1   1    1
2   1   0    1
3   0   0    0
4   0   0    1
5   1   1    0
6   1   1    1
> dog <- sum(x$dog==1 & x$trap==1)/sum(x$dog==1)
> dog
[1] 0.75
> cat <- sum(x$cat==1 & x$trap==1)/sum(x$cat==1)
> cat
[1] 0.6666667
```

I want to get this answer in the least amount of steps for all my 100 species:

```r
[1] dog  0.75
[2] cat  0.6666
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is using `colSums`

```
colSums(x[-3] * x[,3])/colSums(x[-3])
#    dog       cat 
#0.7500000 0.6666667
```

Or with `sapply`

```
sapply(x[1:2], function(y)  sum(y ==1 & x[,3] == 1)/sum(y ==1))
#      dog       cat 
#0.7500000 0.6666667
```

Comment: sorry akrun. I realized just your first answer, when you use mean function. So you are right. The score is for you

Comment: It's okay.  I showed a vectorized solution and thought that it should not be forgotten

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `*apply()` function here, e.g. `sapply()`:

```r
x <-
  data.frame(
    "dog" = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1),
    "bird" = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    "cat" = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
    "trap" = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
  )
sapply(x[, 1:(ncol(x)-1)], function(i) sum(i == 1 & x$trap == 1) / sum(i == 1))
#>       dog      bird       cat 
#> 0.7500000 1.0000000 0.6666667
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>